# Java Swing Apache POI make Word Document read only

Tags: java, swing, file, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

Hello I am creating a Swing application to create a word document. I have made use of the `Apache POI Java API` for this purpose.

But the problem is --> How do I set the word document to be read only after creation?

I have heard of `java.io.File.setReadOnly()` method, but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Here is the code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       try{  
           FileOutputStream outStream=new FileOutputStream("New.docx");
           XWPFDocument doc =new XWPFDocument();

           XWPFParagraph para1=doc.createParagraph();
           para1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
           XWPFRun pararun1= para1.createRun();
           pararun1.setBold(true);
           pararun1.setFontSize(16);
           pararun1.setText(jLabel1.getText());
           pararun1.addBreak();

           XWPFParagraph para2=doc.createParagraph();
           para2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
           XWPFRun pararun2= para2.createRun();
           pararun2.setFontSize(12);
           pararun2.setText("Date : " +jTextField2.getText());
           pararun2.addBreak();

           doc.write(outStream);
           outStream.close();

       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Since I am using the `FileOutputStream` instead of `File` here, how do you suggest I make the word file as read only after it is created?

Comment: Create a `File` object (`File file = new File("New.docx");`), pass that to your `FileOutputStream` - `FileOutputStream outStream=new FileOutputStream(file);`

Comment: Works perfectly, just what I needed thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks